# I am trying to play audio in my code, but it creates error and not working properly

Tags: flutter, flutter-audioplayers

> Error: unable to find directory entry in pubspec.yaml: D:\Flutter\New folder\practice\audio
> E/flutter (10832): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
> Exception: Unable to load asset:
> "assets/assets/audio/sound_alarm.mp3". E/flutter (10832): The asset
> does not exist or has empty data. E/flutter (10832): #0
> PlatformAssetBundle.load.
> (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:254:9) E/flutter
> (10832):  E/flutter (10832): #1
> AudioCache.fetchToMemory
> (package:audioplayers/src/audio_cache.dart:92:22) E/flutter (10832):
>  E/flutter (10832): #2      AudioCache.load
> (package:audioplayers/src/audio_cache.dart:118:31) E/flutter (10832):
>  E/flutter (10832): #3
> AudioPlayer.setSourceAsset
> (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:310:17) E/flutter (10832):
>  E/flutter (10832): #4      _Page2State.play
> (package:practice/page.dart:166:5) E/flutter (10832):

```
 import 'dart:ffi';
    
    import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
    import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart' as audio;
    
    
    class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
      Page2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<Page2> createState() => _Page2State();
    }
    
    class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {
      static AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        // late Source audioUrl = UrlSource('https://www.jiosaavn.com/album/tu-jhoothi-main-makkaar/Zk6,htMIngg_');
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Audio'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // final player = AudioPlayer();
                    //  player.play(audioUrl);
                    play();
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      play() async {
        await player.setSourceAsset('assets/audio/sound_alarm.mp3');
        player.play(
          AssetSource('assets/audio/sound_alarm.mp3'),
        );
      }
    }
```

Pubspec.yml

```
  assets:
- audio/
```

Comment: Notice how the error `assets/assets/audio/sound_alarm.mp3` contains the word assets twice? Try removing the prefix in your code and using `'audio/sound_alarm.mp3'`.

Answer (score 0):

May be the path is not good, there is an indentation, or a letter lacking

```
assets:
- assets/audio/
```

Example:

[image: assets][image: pubspec]

Comment: Not working after this. The Error- A resource failed to call end.